# Access an external message source file in Gradle/Spring/javax

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I am working on a gradle solution with multiple modules.  I have been working on moving the message overwrites to a (secondary) messages.properties file including entries along the lines of

```
validation.account.required=Please enter your account
```

for lookups like

```
@NotNull(message="{validation.account.required}")
private Long account;
```

The application uses Bootstrap and so the validations property file is connected in the Application.class

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messages_validations = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages_additional");
    return messageSource;
}
```

This all works well.  However I would like all modules (data service, app service, utility jars etc) to point to the same external file.  Is there a standard way to do this in the configuration or would I need to write a class loader bean of some sort ?